# When does the Strawberry Panic novel occur relative to the manga?

Tags: strawberry-panic

I got both the [manga](http://www.rightstuf.com/1-800-338-6827/catalogmgr/XSooD9Cg0EJsRFKELV/browse/item/88434/4/0/0) and the [novel](http://www.rightstuf.com/1-800-338-6827/catalogmgr/ToUtSpzZNEsxGhh8IU/browse/item/90641/4/0/0) of Strawberry Panic. While I was reading the back of the novel, I saw that it mentions that the characters are from the 3 schools in the area. One of the schools is the same one the manga is set in, St. Miator Girls' Academy.

So I am wondering, when does the novel occur relative to the manga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The novel takes place at the same time as the manga does and covers the same content. However, the novel covers all of the story, whereas the manga stops about 2/3rds way through.

The manga also has characters from the 3 schools, but the primary characters in both mediums are from St. Miator's.

There may be a couple of characters that differ between the mediums, but they will be minor characters and the cast is mostly the same.